# Adding node to a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

So I'm creating a linked list in C and adding some nodes to it that contain information. I have an if else statement where I create the linked list's head and then add nodes to it. The problem is that when I add a new node I seem to lose the old one. Not sure why this is happening or how to fix this.

Edit: I have made some updates to make it a runnable program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<regex.h>

int main(int argc, char argv[]) {


int head=0, i=0;
char tempCourseID[10], tempCourseGrade[10], tempCourseCH[10];
static struct LinkedList {
char *CourseName;
char *CourseGrade;
char *CourseCreditHours;
struct LinkedList *next;
} LinkedList;

static struct LinkedList *first, *savefirst, *headlist;

first = malloc(sizeof ((*first)));

savefirst = first;
headlist = first;
for(i ; i<5; i++){
printf("Enter Course name");
fgets(tempCourseID, sizeof(tempCourseID), stdin);

printf("Enter Course grade");
fgets(tempCourseGrade, sizeof(tempCourseGrade), stdin);

printf("Enter Course credit hours");
fgets(tempCourseCH, sizeof(tempCourseCH), stdin);
//checks to see if linked list head exists
   if (head == 0) { 
   printf("No head has been found.\n");

   headlist->CourseName = tempCourseID;
   headlist->CourseGrade = tempCourseGrade;
   headlist->CourseCreditHours = tempCourseCH;
   headlist->next = NULL;


   printf("A head has been created\n");
   printf("A node has been added\n");
   head = 1;       
   } else {
   printf("Ahead already exists\n");


   first = malloc(sizeof ((*first)));
   first->CourseName = tempCourseID;
   first->CourseGrade = tempCourseGrade;
   first->CourseCreditHours = tempCourseCH;

   first->next = NULL;
   savefirst->next = first;
   savefirst = first;

   printf("A node has been add\n");
   head = 1;

   }

}

while (headlist != NULL) {
    printf(" %s ", headlist->CourseName);
    printf(" %s ", headlist->CourseGrade);
    printf("%s \n", headlist->CourseCreditHours);
    headlist = headlist->next;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: To really debug this, we need to see what the actual code looks like, and the correct order of events. This would make 1 node every time, and print it.

Comment: `headlist->CourseName = tempCourseID;` and similar probably isn't doing what you think it is doing. This is not copying the string data to those fields, it's simply assigning a pointer to `tempCourseID` to `->CourseName`. There's only one `tempCourseID` in memory, so for every node you make, they're all going to point to `tempCourseID`, and if you printed them all out they would print whatever was entered in `tempCourseID` last. You probably want to allocate some space for each `char*` field in your `struct` and then [`strcpy`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) them over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have char `tempCourseID[10]` and `char* CourseName`

It is legal to use `CourseName = tempCourseID;` however `tempCourseID` is temporary, and so the string will be lost soon. In this case we need to allocate separate memory for `CourseName`, and then copy the value from `tempCourseID`

Use instead

```
CourseName = malloc(strlen(tempCourseID) + 1);//add +1 for null-character
strcpy(CourseName, tempCourseID);

//or

CourseName = strdup(tempCourseID)//shortcut!
```

There are problem with the linked list. You have too many variables with similar names. A linked list needs only `head`. You can introduce a temporary variable `node` for adding new nodes. If you are adding nodes to the tail, then save the last node in the list, lets call it `savenode`

In this example I removed `fgets` functions and replaced it with `sprintf`, that's just to make it easier to run the program and debug. You can put back `fgets` later.

```
int main(int argc, char argv[]) 
{
    struct LinkedList
    {
        char *CourseName;
        char *CourseGrade;
        char *CourseCreditHours;
        struct LinkedList *next;
    };

    int i;
    char tempCourseName[100], tempCourseGrade[100], tempCourseCH[100];
    struct LinkedList *head = NULL;
    struct LinkedList *node = NULL;
    struct LinkedList *savenode = NULL;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        sprintf(tempCourseName, "CourseName %d", i);
        sprintf(tempCourseGrade, "tempCourseGrade %d", i);
        sprintf(tempCourseCH, "tempCourseCH %d", i);

        node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
        node->CourseName = strdup(tempCourseName);
        node->CourseGrade = strdup(tempCourseGrade);
        node->CourseCreditHours = strdup(tempCourseCH);
        node->next = NULL;

        if(head == NULL)
            head = node;

        //check savenode exists
        //this will be the last node (tail) in the existing list
        //get it to point to our new node
        if(savenode)
            savenode->next = node;

        //now we have a new tail
        savenode = node;
    }

    //walk through the list
    node = head;
    while(node) 
    {
        printf("%s, %s, %s\n", 
            node->CourseName, node->CourseGrade, node->CourseCreditHours);
        node = node->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```